# Unknown association between usecases in "usecase" diagram

Tags: uml, use-case

In a project there is a use case "sync" for synchronizing files. Naturally sometimes the "sync" use case needs "downloading files" which is another use case. So there is an association between "sync" and "downloading files"; but "downloading files" does not `extend` "sync", because it is a part of synchronizing and sometimes synchronizing does not complete without that. Although "sync" does not `include` "downloading files";because there are situations that synchronizing does not need to do downloading.

How can I describe this situatin in a use case diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use `include` for situations like that.

It is a common misconception that included use cases must **always** be executed and extending use cases are **optional**.

In fact the main difference between include and extend is more about dependencies than it is about frequency of execution.

From UML 2.5 specs:

> Include is a DirectedRelationship between two UseCases, indicating
>   that the behavior of the included UseCase (the addition) is inserted
>   into the behavior of the including UseCase (the includingCase).
>   [...]
>   The including UseCase may depend on the changes produced by executing
>   the included UseCase. The included UseCase must be available for the
>   behavior of the including UseCase to be completely described.
>   [...]
>   The Include relationship is intended to be used when there are common parts of the 
>   behavior of two or more UseCases. This common part is then extracted
>   to a separate UseCase, to be included by all the base UseCases having
>   this part in common. As the primary use of the Include relationship is
>   for reuse of common parts, what is left in a base UseCase is usually
>   not complete in itself but dependent on the included parts to be
>   meaningful. This is reflected in the direction of the relationship,
>   indicating that the base UseCase depends on the addition but not vice
>   versa.

But be careful with includes and extends. Before you know it you'll be describing each function of the system as a use case, which kind of defeats its purpose.

Comment: `UML 2.5 specs` says: `"All of the behavior of the included UseCase is executed at a single location in the included UseCase before execution of the including UseCase is resumed."`. Does it mean that ` included use cases must always be executed`?

Comment: I think `single location` can also also be a location in an alternate scenario => thus not always executed. The main point of that phrase is that the whole included use case is executed, and only after that the main use case continues. You cannot first execute the first part of the included use case, then do few things in the main use case, and then execute a second part of the use case.

Answer (score -1):

If *downloading part* is always a part of *sync* (i.e. it can be called only from *sync* but not from some other UC or as an independent UC) then *downloading part* is a part of *sync* and as such **should not be decomposed as a separate UC**. The fact it doesn't happen always doesn't change a thing here (it's just an alternate flow).

If *downloading part* is a separate UC (i.e. can be run independently or - still discouraged to make it separate UC - can be called from some other UC) but it is run only during some runs of *sync* then it is the **extend** type of relationship (arrow pointing from *downloading part* to *sync*)

If *downloading part* is a separate UC (like above) but it is run each time *sync* is run (i.e. it's part of each flow of *sync*) then it's the **include** type of relationship (arrow pointing from *sync* to *downloading part*).

To my understanding it either isn't a separate UC at all or it is **extend**. The fact that:

> because it is a part of synchronizing and sometimes synchronizing does not complete without that.

suggests it's just not a separate UC (so just drop it from your diagram).

Yet if it can be a separate UC, then in this part:

> Although "sync" does not include "downloading files";because there are situations that synchronizing does not need to do downloading.

you're right - it cannot be **include** leaving you only with **extend** option (which is right). The mere fact that it is - as you said - part of *sync* (meaning it is triggered by *sync* and provides results to it) is exactly what is needed for it to be the **extend**.

Comment: Can you explain how you reach the conclusion that an include cannot be optional (e.g. called in an alternate scenario)? I have not found that in the UML specs. Also, it seems like the `sync` use case would be depending on the results of `download files` so in that case an `extend` would definitely not be allowed.